# Расположить строки матрицы в порядке возрастания характеристик

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Дана целочисленная матрица. Характеристика строки матрицы определяется суммой её чётных элементов. Расположить строки матрицы в порядке возрастания характеристик.

Вот мой код, не понимаю где ошибка и как её исправить.

```
 const
      n = 3;
    var
      a: array [1..n, 1..n] of integer;
      an: array [1..n] of integer;
      ak: array [1..n] of integer;
      i, j, k, m, sum: integer;
    begin
      randomize;
      for i := 1 to n do
      begin
        an[i] := 0;
        for j := 1 to n do
          a[i, j] := random(10) - 5; 
      end;
      for i := 1 to n do
      begin
        for j := 1 to n do
          write(a[i, j]:5);
        writeln;
      end;
      writeln;
      for i := 1 to n do
      begin
      sum:=0;
        for j := 1 to n do
        begin
          if (a[i, j] mod 2 = 0) and (a[i, j] >= 0) then
            sum := sum + a[i, j];
          an[i] := sum;
        end;
     end; 
      for i := 1 to n - 1 do
        for j := 1 to n - i do
          if an[j] > an[j+1] then
          begin
            k := an[j];
            an[j] := an[j + 1];
            an[j + 1] := an[j];
            for m := 1 to n do
            begin
              ak[m] := a[j, m];
              a[j, m] := a[j + 1, m];//строки матрицы меняются по пузырьковому методу
              a[j + 1, m] := ak[m];
            end;
          end;
      for i := 1 to n do
      begin
        for j := 1 to n do
          write(a[i, j]:5);
        writeln;
      end;

      write(' Упорядоченные характеристики строк матрицы: ');
      write(an);
      end.
```

Начальная матрица:

```
2    2   -4
1    1   -1
2   -5    4
```

Характеристики строк матрицы:

```
  4  0  6
```

Отсортированная матрица:

```
1    1   -1
2    2   -4
2   -5    4
```

Отсортированные характеристики строк:

```
  0  0  6
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "четностью элемента", поясните, пожалуйста.  У вас проверяется четность значения. У меня же возникла мысль, что нужно считать сумму только четных элементов строки по индексу (ответ уже дан другим участником)

Comment: `0 4 6 ` в конце там.

Comment: @teran опечатка, наверное

Answer (score 0):

В условии задачи ничего нет про неотрицательность четных элементов, а в Вашем коде - есть:

```
if (a[i, j] mod 2 = 0) and (a[i, j] >= 0) then
```

Выведите эту суммы чётных элементов и сравните их значения с порядком отсортированных строк.

*Update*

```
k := an[j];
an[j] := an[j + 1];
an[j + 1] := k; // была ошибка: an[j + 1] := an[j];
```

Comment: Ах, да. Сумма чётных и одновременно положительных. Забыл в условие задачи дописать.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример начальной матрицы, массив сумм и выходную (отсортированную) матрицу.